# Wordpress 404 after manual install

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

My core wordpress files got hacked because of a plug in. My site started giving malicious redirects.

While trying to edit wp-config.php, my site went fully offline. I tried a full manual reinstall because of this and I needed new core files anyway. My site is still not online.  I have the database, database password, and username in wp-config.php. Also, I have everything in the document root for the correct domain. Maybe there is some conflict between the two domains with my host?

Does anybody know what might be causing this 404. I can't get access to the dashboard.

I got a backup before doing anything and I downloaded wp-content. The original database is still available.

I tried an automated install through cpanel with fresh everything and this would not get me to a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 404 error is not because you can't connect to your database. You should see Database connection error message if database is the problem. Did you edit .htaccess file maybe? You can try to remove everything there and put default one for Wordpress.

Comment: I have not edited .htaccess. I was just looking for it. It's in a plugin folder for some reason. wp-content/plugins/akismet/.htaccess            When I have edited .htaccess I don't think it was placed like this.

Comment: Try to rename plugins folder to ".plugins" in wp-content to check if some plugin is causing the problem. If so, then you can narrow to problem for specific plugin that causing the problem in the same way, renaming folder of specific plugin.

Answer (score 0):

May be your site compromised. Deactivate the plugins using the file manager provided by your host and rename **wp-content/plugins** to **wp-content/plugins-old**, also deactivate the theme or rename the **wp-admin** folder on root directory and then take a try to login. Also turn on the debugger.

Comment: I tried those three things without success. The debugger is on by a wp-config.php edit. I don't see a log on the url. I keep seeing installation guides talking about the public_html folder. Does wordpress allows get installed there?  I installed somewhere else because I have two domains.